# Foundation search feature is not working

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search

Our IT dept recently had someone come help with some SharePoint configuration issues.  The problem now is that the search feature (that was working properly before) is now not working in any of the sites.  Here's the message I get:

*We did not find any results for ***_*___**:
Suggestions:
•Ensure words are spelled correctly.
•Try using synonyms or related searches.
•Try broadening your search by searching from a different site.
Additional resources:
•Get additional search tips by visiting Search Help
•If you cannot find a page that you know exists, contact your administrator.**

I've checked to make sure that the site is allowed to appear in search results and that all web parts can be indexed.

Any suggestions on what our IT dept. needs to check to get this working again.  They are not SP savvy and it's been over two weeks waiting for their help.  My role is as a SharePoint admin. and the power user on the support staff.

Thanks for any recommendation on getting this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check Indexing Schedule value, which service account run service if it has permissions and maybe restart service?